# Pass reducer in functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm stuck on passing reducer in my react functional component,
Please help me to fix this.

Here is my reducer :

```
  export const addPost = (value : String) => {
     return {
         type:actionTypes.ADD_POST,
         value,
     }
}
```

I'm trying to pass props but it is giving me error in my functional component,Any suggestions?

Func component:

```
 const Posts : React.FunctionComponent = () => {

   
    const submitPost = () => {
        let {addPost} = props.addPost
        let titleValue  = titleRef.current
        let descriptionValue = descriptionRef.current
        if (titleValue && descriptionValue) {
            if ( titleValue.value  === '' || descriptionValue.value === '' ) {
                toast.info('Could not add new topic')
            } else {
                axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/addPost`, {
                    title : titleValue.value,
                    description : descriptionValue.value,
                    username : localStorage.getItem('username')
                })
                    .then((res) => {
                        toast.info('Topic added succesfuly')
                        history.push('/homepage')
                        console.log('--------res', res);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log('--------err', err);
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using ```useDispatch``` from ```'react-redux```.?

Comment: `it is giving me error` could you please add the entire error?

Comment: Seems you're missing the `props` parameter in your Posts function.

Comment: I think it should be `let {addPost} = props;` but then you never use it after that so maybe it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functional component, import useDispatch.

If suppose your action file name containing your all actions is myActions.js then you may import all actions like

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './myActions'
```

Now using useDispatch you can pass your action in it.

In your component use, it like this

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 dispatch(actions.addPost())
```

Comment: dispatch(actions.addPost()) <- after this it will automatically execute addpost function right?

Comment: Yes, it will dispatch an action to redux just the same way connected class component does it

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass value in the dispatch? I'm doing it like this                             dispatch({type:"ADD_POST"})
But i dont know how to pass the value in it

Comment: You can just directly pass in it. Suppose you want to pass the string "Nika", then you may do like dispatch(actions.addPost("Nika"))